# emacs lisp library for input forms?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs Lisp (elisp), if I want to get several values from the user, is there a better
way than just asking for each value in turn in the minibuffer?

Ideally, there would be a library that would let me define an input form with several
fields, present that form to the user (as a text-based dialog in text mode, and as a
GUI-based dialog in GUI mode), and let me query the results.   A text-only library
would be fine too.

Is there any such library?

thanks!

ilya

Answer (score 13):

There is the **Emacs Widget Library**. (`C-h i m Widget RET` for info)
You can create text fields, check boxes, buttons, etc. in an emacs buffer. In a graphical frame it is more graphical, but still in a buffer, just like in a customize buffer, which uses the widget library.

Comment: Excellent answer, but the keybinding sequence for help doesn't work with my Emacs.  I found good info at [the creator's site](http://www.dina.kvl.dk/~abraham/custom/widget.html), though.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of values are they?  You could use Customize, which has many more options than most GUI dialog boxes.